# Images in docx file move when I reopen the file with Libreoffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer, docx

I'm using LibreOffice 4.0.0 to document my project, and I have a lot images in the document (.docx file).

But, after I place the images in their correct location, save and close LibreOffice Writer and then open the file again, I find the images are all over the place!

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to make sure that the images stay where they belong and not jump around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibreOffice and MS Office don't handle each other's formats very well. OpenOffice's OOXML support is supposed to be a tad better.

Contrarily to what others said before, Word can actually open ODT files. Sadly, this only works properly if Word saved them itself.

If you want to keep using LibreOffice, since it's generally impossible to teach everyone you exchange documents with how to open ODT files, there are only two options I've had success with:

- Save your files as ODT and use a good ODF to OOXML converter.

  It's a little cumbersome, but you can upload your document to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) and download it in a different format. Of all the converters I've tried, Google Docs yielded the best results.
- If you require distributing a read-only document, export them as PDF with LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1):

`.docx` is actually an XML-based format, and is more "open" than the old proprietary `.doc` format was. However, the XML processing logic inside Microsoft Word is still closed-source, and while LibreOffice (and others) may try and emulate it as best they can, there likely still will be some differences in rendering between the two programs. `.odt` is also XML-based, and I quickly found [this plugin](http://odf-converter.sourceforge.net/) that lets you read them in MS Word, although you may run into the same formatting/display issues you're seeing now going in the other direction.

If you truly want formatting to stay as close to the original as possible, safe your documents as PDF files. That is a standard that everyone understands, especially when it comes to image placement. Different programs have varying abilities to *edit* PDF files that have already been created (I sprang for Acrobat 11, and I love it), but if you're just going for consistent presentation then PDF is the way to go.